# Drop Database from Django Admin

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I'm creating a functionality that allows an admin to drop a database from the Django admin. However, I keep getting errors that a drop database cannot be execute from a transaction block or that the database is open.

I have tried solutions placed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408156/how-to-drop-a-postgresql-database-if-there-are-active-connections-to-it) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357856/postgres-cannot-drop-database-using-psycopg2), either writing it in a template and executing from SQLAlchemy directly but no luck.

My current code block is this

```
    engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql_string')
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
    session.close_all()
    engine.dispose()
    session.autocommit = True
    session.connection().connection.set_isolation_level(0)
    session.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test_db;')
    session.connection().connection.set_isolation_level(1)
```

But it still will throw an error even when I terminated all activity from `pg_stat_activity`, any other ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: Are you trying to drop the whole database or a single table?

Comment: Where does this code sit in the project? It's a difficult thing to help with because a database connection could come from anywhere.